# In Js cookie html tags have gone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, encoding

I have a html text in js cookie. When i tried to get the text in cookie and set that text in a html  div, it becomes encoded. I tried to decode the html but no use.

This is my code:

```
function addToCoupon(team1,team2,id,bet,rate){

    var betTableContent=$('#bet_table').html();
    var row="<tr><td>"+team1+"-"+team2+"</td><td>"+bet+"</td><td>"+rate+"</td></tr>";

      betTableContent+=row;

    $.cookie("coupon",betTableContent);
    $('#bet_table').html(unescape($.cookie("coupon")));
```

}

My text in #bet_table looks as  not matter if I use unescape() function or not:

```
%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EHapoel%20Nazareth%20Elite-Maccabi%20Herzliya%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3E1X2
```

So how can I display this html text as normal html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape it before you create it and then unescape it like this

```
jQuery.cookie('coupon', escape('<html></html>'));
console.log(unescape(jQuery.cookie('coupon')));
```

Comment: At first time your solution correct, but when i refresh page, the problem occurs again

Comment: Clear your old cookies before the refresh.

Comment: cleared cache and cookies,  but in the cookie the value is encoded i checked in chrome-console.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be encoded, but by calling escape and then unescape you control the encoding